# How do I find the 'default' visibility for a google Calender Item?

Tags: google-calendar-api

Looking at [the calendar event documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events), one of the possible values for visibility is:

> "default" - Uses the default visibility for events on the calendar. This is the default value.

I'd like to find out, if I see this value on an event, what visibility that event is. In other words, where do I find the default? Is it fixed, is it a property of the Calendar or the user or ..? I looked at all those I could think of but did not find any reference to visibility.

After searching some more, [this](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/34580?hl=en) might be the clue: it's user documentation, and it says (with much left out):

> First, learn your calendar's privacy settings
>
> Next, learn your event sharing options:
>
> > My calendar isn't shared with anyone
> >
> > > Your calendar isn't shared with anyone, so your events aren't either.
> > >       No matter which settings you choose for your event, the event will only be seen by you.
> >
> > I've only shared my calendar with specific people
> >
> > > See only free/busy
> > >
> > > > Default: Events show as busy.
> > >
> > > See all event details
> > >
> > > > Default: People you've shared your calendar with can see all event details.
> > >
> > > Make changes to events OR Make changes to events and manage sharing
> > >
> > > > For the default, public, and private settings, people you've shared your calendar with can see and change any event details.

But now I'm stuck finding the calender's privacy settings.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is exactly, `visibility` is a writable property of [`Events`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events?hl=en). `default` is its default value (regardless if you set it or not). Do you mean who's able to access the `Events` with a default `visibility`? That will depend if the calendar is shared (as with what you cited).

Comment: Yes that is what I'm looking for: if an events visibility is set to default, what does that mean. (It turns out to be way more complex than I anticipated.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default visibility means that the visibility of the calendar applies to this specific event. If the calendar is publicly shared free-busy then the event will be displayed with no event details (just the time).
If the calendar is only shared read-only with your friend then this friend will see full details of the event while other people would not see anything.